# Error while adding any field in custom content type

Tags: drupal-7

I am unable to add any field in my custom content type, when I click on save button or click on upload after adding images it gives me the following error and for the text field the error is simply `Exception thrown without a stack frame in unknown on lne 0`, after this a white screen appears. :
[image]

After this website appears to be blank until I import the database again.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution, by changing `max_allowed_packet` in `wamp>my.ini` from `1m` to `16m`. It works for me.